# Programmatically change the icons/names of homescreen apps in Android

Tags: android, icons, homescreen

I'd like to build an app that allows me to change the icons and names of my homescreen apps. It's basically like what ADW Launcher does, but I don't want any of the other features it has to offer (namely, it strips away the rest of the ICS goodies like the blue end-scroll glow and panel pivots). I just want to be able to set custom icons and names for my homescreen apps. I am new to Android development and was wondering if you can point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I don't want to permanently change an app's icon/name, rather I just want modify it as it appears on my home screen (not in the app drawer). Similar to ADW or GO lauchers... a shortcut rather than the actual executable?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You can't. It's not possible to change the resources packaged with the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this if you rewrite the Launcher code, there is NO other way.